# coldfusion file upload problems

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion

Uploading the File and I am confused why it is behaving like thiDoing this Way:

Action Page

```
<cftry>
<cfset filename = form.uploading>
<cfset form.settingsID = form.id>
<cfset Savepath= Application.uploadPath &"/" & "_images/_logo">
<cfif len(form.uploading)>
    <cfset cffile = Application.sys.UploadFile(FileField = form.uploading,destination = '#Savepath#/')>
    <cfset uploadfile = cffile.ServerFile>
</cfif>

<cfset form.uploadedfiles = uploadfile>
<cfset results = Application.tools.updateLogo(form)>
<cflocation addtoken="false" url="uploadMaster.cfm?msg=complete&sid=#form.settingsID#">
<cfcatch>
    <cfif FileExists('#Savepath#/#filename#')>
        <cffile action="delete" file="#Savepath#/#filename#">
    </cfif>
    <cflocation addtoken="false" url="uploadMaster.cfm?msg=error&sid=#form.settingsID#&i=#cfcatch.message#">
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Using the function from cflib to Upload

> http://cflib.org/udf/uploadFile

what I am doing wrong, I am always getting the error

```
The form field C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/runtime/work/Catalina/localhost/tmp/neotmp2781363863529598577.tmp did not contain a file.
```

My Form Page has form as following

```
<cfform method="post" action="uploadmasterAction.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table align="center" width="100%" class="table table-striped ddclass">
    <tr><td>
        Logo File
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td><cfinput required="true" message="Please Upload Image File" type="file" name="uploading" id="uploading">
    <cfinput type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="#sid#"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</cfform>
```

Comment: Strictly a guess.  This `FileField = form.uploading` needs quotes around form.uploading.

Comment: That seems to be solving it, damm man this 2016 cf is getting very strict

Comment: It has nothing to do with 2016. The udf expects the *name* of a form field, but you are passing in its *value* instead.

Comment: ok, i tried using normal cffile upload and wrapped with quotes but it did not worked, only after a failed attempt, i used this udf and it has nothing fancy, not sure why it worked this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific problem was caused by this bit of code:

```
FileField = form.uploading
```

You had to quote `form.uploading`.

On a more general note, the example in the udf showed the use of quotes.  You missed it, but then again, I miss stuff like that all the time.  That's why I have so much practice reading error messages.

Regarding your earlier attempt using a normal `cffile` tag, whatever error you encountered was not caused by quoting the name of the form field.  You are supposed to.  However, if you look at the example [the documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html), you will see that the name of the form field is not preceded by the word 'form'.  That may have been what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks @dan, The Docs makes sense